# Problemas con el icono de html

Tags: html, css, html5

Empecé hace relativamente poco tiempo a programar y ahora estoy haciendo mi portafolio. El día de ayer, realicé el modo oscuro en mi portafolio y funcionaba correctamente hasta hoy que empecé a escribir más líneas para mejorar el mismo.

Practicamente está ahí, pero no se ve y no sé la verdad el porqué. Ya busqué: en el CSS lo mande a llamar correctamente, en el HTML todo esta linkeado, y el javascript no lo he movido para nada.

Así es como se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá está el código:

```js
const daynight = document.querySelector('.day-night');
daynight.addEventListener('click', () => {
  daynight.querySelector('i').classList.toggle('fa-sun');
  daynight.querySelector('i').classList.toggle('fa-moon');
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark')
})

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  if (document.body.classList.contains('dark')) {
    daynight.querySelector('i').classList.add('fa-sun');
  } else daynight.querySelector('i').classList.add('fa-moon');
})
```

```css
.style-dark-day {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 60px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.style-dark-day .s-icon {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: var(--bg-black-100);
  color: var(--text-black-900);
  right: 100%;
  border: 1px solid var(--bg-black-50);
  margin-right: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.style-dark-day .icon i {
  line-height: 40px;
}

.style-dark-day .day-night {
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/Color-1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/dist/boxicons.js"></script>
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>


<div class="style-dark-day">
  <div class="day-night s-icon">
    <i class="fas "></i>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- links js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.12/typed.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="assets/style-dark.js"></script>
<script src="assets/script.js"></script>
```

Estaba revisando el codigo y borrando lo que había hecho y esto fue lo que borré y volvió a aparecer el icono del modo dark. Si comento este pedacito de código, el modo oscuro se vuelve visible, pero si lo descomento se desaparece. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se quede fijo?

Esto es el CSS:

```
.section .back-section {
    z-index: 1;
}

.section.active {
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: slideSection 1s ease;
}

@keyframes slideSection {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: 0%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Nicolas, bienvenido, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. Y de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: No estimado, debes editar tu pregunta. presionar el icono `<>` y colocar tu código html, css y js donde corresponda. Además debe ser un ejemplo mínimo el que pongas, no todo el proyecto, solo lo necesario para reproducir el problema [MRE]

Comment: creo que ahora si :c lo siento es mi primera vez

Comment: solo como nota.. no es un foro, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas.. tu pregunta parece completa, seguro alguien con experiencia podra ayudarte...

Comment: gracias gbianchi

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si le pones un `z-index: 3` al icono? Parece que la sección tiene un z-index de 2, y como el icono no tiene z-index, puede acabar por debajo de la sección. Por eso aparecería en el DOM, pero no estaría visible. Y por eso se resolvería el problema al quitar el código que mencionas (porque pone z-index a `.section`).

Comment: gracias alvaro ya funciona

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro mejor ponerlo como respuesta, así se ve mejor

Answer (score 0):

La causa es que la sección tiene un `z-index` de 2, y como el icono no tiene `z-index`, acaba por debajo de la sección. Por eso aparece en el DOM, pero no está visible (está visible pero tapado). Y por eso, cuando quitas el código que mencionas (que incluye el `z-index` en `.section`) sí puedes ver el icono.

Una solución sería poner un `z-index: 3` al icono. Al ser mayor que de la sección, se mostrará por encima.